# How to create a UML Class diagram with react JS

Tags: reactjs, class, uml, class-diagram

I'm newer in Web developpement (I have modest knowledge about it).
I'm asked in my university-project to develop a webapp that generates a UML class diagram using ReactJS.
I've installed nodeJS, webstorm, I tested a "hello world" code, it works but I don't know how to generate this digram, from where start.
In reality, I've tested the library storm-react-diagram, but I didn't get any result.
Please , someone can help me, orient me or propse me any template, any code that works to be inspired. really I'm lost.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check mxgraph or jointjs this two libraries will help you in your project also you need to be more clear specifying your project because it depends if you are going to generate the diagrams by using drag and drop method or something else

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't need a drag-drop . but I have to generate automatically a Class diagram according to a given database